# Use Class property inside of a method's function

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to use `myVar` inside my of a method's function. I have already tried adding `global` but still nothing. I know this is probably basic but I can't seem to find it.

```
class myClass{
  
  public $myVar;

  public function myFunction() {
  
    function myInnerFunction() {
      //how do I use this variable here
      echo $this->myVar; 
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I try using `$this` I get this error: 'Using $this when not in object context in...'

Comment: use private or protected methods. You just defined a global function. You can even try using `create_function` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)

Comment: `function myInnerFunction` makes that function *global* (but only after `myFunction` is called).  Is `myInnerFunction` being called from outside of `myFunction`?  Where does `myInnerFunction` get called from?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `$this->myVar`

See the [PHP Documentation - The Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#example-166)

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
    // property declaration
    public $var = 'a default value';

    // method declaration
    public function displayVar() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}
?>
```

> The pseudo-variable **$this** is available when a method is called from
>   within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object
>   (usually the object to which the method belongs

***Update:***

In your new code sample, `myInnerFunction` is a [nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415969/what-are-php-nested-functions-for) and is not accessible until the `myFunction` method is called.  Once the `myFunction` method is called, the `myInnerFunction` becomes part of the `global` scope.

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
 class myClass{

  public $myVar;

  public function myFunction() {

  }

  function myInnerFunction() {
    //how do I use this variable here
    echo $this->myVar; 
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry. I have already tried that but forgot to put it in the snippet above. I just updated the code to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

Inner functions like `myInnerFunction` are always global in scope, even if they are defined inside of a member function in a class.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747908/scope-of-declared-function-within-a-function) for another similar example

So, to PHP, the following are (almost) equivalent:

```
class myClass{

  public $myVar;

  public function myFunction() {

    function myInnerFunction() {
      //how do I use this variable here
      echo $this->myVar; 
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
class myClass{

  public $myVar;

  public function myFunction() {

  }
}

function myInnerFunction() {
   //how do I use this variable here
   echo $this->myVar; 
}
```

Hopefully the second example illustrates why `$this` is not even in scope for `myInnerFunction`.  The solution is simply to pass the variable as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as an argument to the inner function.

Comment: Perhaps the OP would find an example helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ReflectionProperty`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php):

```
$prop = new ReflectionProperty("SimpleClass", 'var');
```

Full example:

```
class myClass{

  public $myVar;

  public function myFunction() {

    function myInnerFunction() {
      //how do I use this variable here
      $prop = new ReflectionProperty("SimpleClass", 'myVar');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution above is good when you need each instance to have an own value. If you need all instances to have a same you can use static:

```
class myClass
{
  public static $myVar = "this is my var's value";

  public function myClass() {
      echo self::$myVar;
  }
}

new myClass();
```

[see here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)